# C++ : Double Destructor Call in Matrix class

Tags: c++

I am currently learning C++ and I wrote some code. Unfortunately I am stuck at a runtime behavior, which I don't quite understand. I am sure it is just a silly coding mistake on my side, but I can't get my head around why this happends.

I wrote myself a little matrix class, with simple operator overloading. It is stored inside Matrix.cpp

```
#include <iostream>


class Matrix {
    int** data;
    int rows;
    int cols;

public:
    Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
        data = new int* [rows];
        this->rows = rows;
        this->cols = cols;

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            data[i] = new int [cols];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                data[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    ~Matrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            delete[] data[i];
        }
        delete[] data;
    }

    Matrix operator + (Matrix matrix) {
        if (matrix.cols != cols && matrix.rows != rows) {
            throw "Matrizies have not the same Dimensions";
        }
        Matrix erg = Matrix(rows, cols);

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                erg.data[i][j] = data[i][j] + matrix.data[i][j];
            }
        }

        return erg;
    }

    Matrix operator + (int scalar) {
        Matrix erg = Matrix(rows, cols);

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                erg.data[i][j] += this->data[i][j] + scalar;
            }
        }

        return erg;
    }
}
```

I am running the code from Main.cpp with the following code

```
#include "Matrix.cpp"

int main()
{
    Matrix matrix1 = Matrix(1, 1);
    Matrix matrix2 = Matrix(1, 1);
    Matrix matrix1Erg(1, 1);
    Matrix matrix2Erg(1, 1);

    matrix1Erg = matrix1 + 1;
    matrix2Erg = matrix2 + 2;
    Matrix matrixErg = matrix1 + matrix2;
}
```

I followed the behaviour of the code with the debugger. The allocation of memory and creation of the matrix works. When calling the overloaded '+', the code is working aswell.
However, after the addition of *matrix1 + 1* the *destructor* is called twice.

I understand the first call, because the Matrix *erg* , which I created in the overloaded parameter function, is out of scope when the function is returning the matrix.
But I don't quite understand, why it would be called a second time.

I am sure it is a really stupid mistake by me, but I hope someone can help me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)

Comment: Your `Matrix` class lacks a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator.  Therefore it is a no-go as far as implementing a correct `operator +` that returns `Matrix` by value.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  Your code fails for something as simple as this:  `int main() { Matrix m1(3,3); Matrix m2(4,4); m1 = m2; }`

Comment: *I wrote myself a little matrix class* -- If that's the case, use `std::vector<std::vector<int>> data` instead of `int ** data`, and your problems may just magically disappear, all with **less** code you need to write (the destructor would be completely unnecessary), and the constructor would be practically zero-lines of code.

Comment: Thank you very much, the comments and article was very helpful and I was able to solve the problem.
std::vector is the norm when programming multidimensional datastructures?